# Status bar flickers while opening another activity

Tags: android, android-layout

When I go from full screen Splash Activity to my next activity, status bar shows weird flickering behaviour.

I have tried this code before finishing the Splash Activity -

```
   Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SplashActivity.this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    });
```

Also my min API level is 19. so: 
`getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
  getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);` this isn't helping either.

My Splash Activity has these style implemented in Manifest:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I figured out there's no solution for this yet. So I made my Splash Activity status bar same color as the Activity background. And it's a fine solution for me currently.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for min SDK 21.
Splash Activity has these style implemented in Manifest:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes I have discovered that later. Thank you!